# How to have checkbox selection in datatable with instant row selection?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I use primefaces 3.0.1 and I have a problem with my datatable.

I use my datatable with the instant row selection. That works very well.
But I wish use in the same time the checkbox selection (for exemple, for select some rows and delete the selected rows)

And when I use the

```
<p:column selectionMode="multiple" />
```

the checkbox are display, but I can't check any checkbox....

Anyone have a solution ?

Thanks.

P.S. : 
my code

```
<p:dataTable id="rows" var="row" value="#{myBean.row}" selection="#{myBean.selectedRow}" selectionMode="single">
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{myBean.onRowSelect}" update="@form"/>

    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:18px" />
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{row.subject}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkboxes are to be used for multiple row selection, but you've still declared your `<p:dataTable>` for single row selection. Remove `selectionMode="single"` from the `<p:dataTable>` and make sure that the `#{myBean.selectedRow}` is changed to be an array instead.

E.g.

```
<p:dataTable ... selection="#{myBean.selectedRows}">
```

with

```
private Row[] selectedRows;
```

Comment: Yes, but like this, I can't use the instant selection...  

I wish have the checkbox selection and the instant selection in the same time...  

I think I must use `<p:commandButton>`... No ?

Comment: Is it possible to have instant selection along with checkbox selection ?